# How do i create multiple class objects that doesn't delete itself after a loop

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I've been trying to create multiple object in a loop and store in it in a map, however it tends to get destroyed after the loop, which i understand but i want to store those objects in a map for future use.

After some debugging **i found the map is only saving 1 object instead of 5** why is that and how can i improve on it?

[image: The code i am working with]

Comment: Please post your code **as text** directly in your question instead of posting a link of an image of your code.

Comment: *After some debugging i found the map is only saving 1 object instead of 5 why is that* -- You are storing the address of a local variable.  What happens when that local variable gets destroyed?

Comment: Does it have to be a pointer?

Comment: To be exact your code have to be fixed, not improved. As a quick fix you can declare declare your tmp as EnemySprite* and initialize it with new.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Unless `EnemySprite` or `tmp` is defined as macro, `EnemySprite tmp(x,y,40,40);` is an local variable, which will be destroyed at the end of scope (end of one iteration in this case).

To avoid deletion, you should dynamically allocate memory.

```
EnemySprite* tmp = new EnemySprite(x,y,40,40);
SDL_Texture* tmpTex = tmp->set_image(".../enemy.png",renderer);

map.insert(std::pair<EnemySprite*, SDL_Texture*>(tmp, tmpTex));
```

Comment: didn't downvote, but prefer storing by value or smart pointer; most people should never write `new`.

Comment: Okay that worked! thank you for the suggestion. Going to read upon dynamic memory allocation ^^ cheers for the help ma man!!!!!!!! <3